# MLP classification fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, sklearn-pandas

I'm new to Machine Learning and I'm working on a python application that classifies poker hands using a dataset which I will post snippets. It does not seem to work well. And I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-62-0d21cd839ce4>", line 1, in <module>
    mlp.fit(X_test, y_train.values.reshape(len(y_train), 1))
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 618, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 330, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 902, in _validate_input
    multi_output=True)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 531, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6253, 18757]
```

here is the code I am trying to produce:

```
import pandas as pnd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

training_data = pnd.read_csv("train.csv")
training_data['id'] = range(1, len(training_data) + 1)  # For 1-base index
training_datafile = training_data
target = training_datafile['hand']
data = training_datafile.drop(['id', 'hand'], axis=1)
X = data
y = target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
X_train.shape
y_train.shape
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100, 100))
mlp.fit(X_test, y_train.values.reshape(len(y_train), 1))
predictions = mlp.predict(X_test)
len(mlp.coefs_)
len(mlp.coefs_[0])
len(mlp.intercepts_[0])
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```

The shape of X_train.shape is (18757, 10) and the shape of y_train.shape is (18757,)
I have tried using following previous post

```
y_train.values.reshape(len(y_train), 1)
```

But I still get the same error. Some guidance would be of much help since I am not sure of what the shape has wrong.

Data snippet:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fiting `X_test` instead of `X_train`.

```
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train.values.reshape(len(y_train), 1))
```